# How do I change between templates to display different media in Meteor/Jscript

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am currently trying to have 3 separate templates that the user can switch between by clicking on one of 3 buttons. By using a session variable ('currentContent'), 3 buttons and 3 templates I cannot see what's going wrong with my current code.

In my javascript:

```
 Template.priority.helpers({
  expensesbtn:function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') ==='expenses'?true:false;
  },
  custombtn:function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') ==='cexpenses'?true:false;
  },
  incomebtn:function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') ==='earning'?true:false;
  },


});

Template.priority.events({
"click #expensesbtn":function(event, template){
  Session.set('currentContent', 'expenses')
},
"click #custombtn":function(event, template){
  Session.set('currentContent', 'cexpenses')
},
"click #incomebtn":function(event, template){
  Session.set('currentContent', 'earning')
}

});
```

and then in my html:

```
  {{>priority}}
       {{#if cexpenses}}
           {{> cexpenses}}
       {{/if}}
       {{#if expenses}}
           {{> expenses}}
       {{/if}}
       {{#if earning}}
           {{> earning}}
       {{/if}}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sindis is right, your helper names must match what you are calling in your templates. But another problem is that while the conditionals aren't inside a template named `priority`, your helpers are attached to the `priority` template, so they wouldn't be recognized even if the names match. You can fix this by putting everything inside the priority template and separating the buttons out into a separate sub-template if that is your intention.

You can also make your code much more elegant [and DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using only one session variable `chosenTemplate` and only one helper and avoiding repeating all those conditionals. Then use Meteor's [`Template.dynamic` feature](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) to display the correct template. Here is an example solution below. Make a new template called `templateControl` and place the buttons inside it. Then place everything inside the `priority` template.

```
<template name="priority">
  {{> templateControl }}
  {{> Template.dynamic template=chosenTemplate }}
</template>

<template name="templateControl">
  {{#each buttons}}
    <button id="{{ id }}" class="chose-template">{{ label }}</button>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.templateControl.helpers
  buttons: [
    { id: 'incomebtn', label: 'Income' },
    { id: 'expensesbtn', label: 'Expenses' },
    { id: 'custombtn', label: 'Custom' }
  ]

Template.templateControl.events
  'click .chose-template': function(e, t) {
    Session.set('chosenTemplate', this.id);
  }

Template.priority.helpers
  chosenTemplate: function(e, t) {
    return Session.get('chosenTemplate');
  }
```

Then be sure to give the three templates you switch between names corresponding to the template ids set in the `chosenTemplate` Session variable!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers have to be the same when you use them in HTML, so your js should look like:

```
Template.priority.helpers({
  expenses: function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') === 'expenses';
  },
  cexpenses: function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') === 'cexpenses';
  },
  earning: function(){
   return Session.get('currentContent') === 'earning';
  }
});
```